# How do I rename multiple files by removing characters in bash?

Tags: bash, rename

I have to rename multiple files in directory by removing first 5 characters for each filename.
How can I do this i bash/shell? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple for loop with a bit of `sed` will do the trick:

```
% touch xxxxx{foo,bar,baz}
% ls -l xxxxx{foo,bar,baz}
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesog  wheel  0 29 Dec 18:07 xxxxxbar
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesog  wheel  0 29 Dec 18:07 xxxxxbaz
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesog  wheel  0 29 Dec 18:07 xxxxxfoo  
% for file in xxxxx*; do mv $file $(echo $file | sed -e 's/^.....//'); done
% ls -l foo bar baz
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesog  wheel  0 29 Dec 18:07 bar
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesog  wheel  0 29 Dec 18:07 baz
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesog  wheel  0 29 Dec 18:07 foo
```

The substitute [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in `sed` says to match any five characters (`.` means any character) at the start of the string (`^`) and remove it.

Answer (score 10):

Bash has some amazing scripting possibilities.  Here's one way:

```
for file in ??????*; do mv $file `echo $file | cut -c6-`; done
```

A handy way to test what it *would* do is to add an echo in front of the command:

```
for file in ??????*; do echo mv $file `echo $file | cut -c6-`; done
```

The six question marks ensure that you only attempt to do this to filenames longer than 5 characters.

Answer (score 6):

All great answers, thanks. This is what worked in my case:

```
rename 's/^.......//g' *
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use sed to do this

```
for file in * ; do mv $file  $(echo $file |sed 's/^.\{5\}//g'); done
```

Answer (score 1):

My two cents':

```
for file in *; do mv $file ${file:5}; done
```

`${file:n}` removes the first `n` characters in the string `file`.

Comment: most elegant answer.